# CI determine the rule activated

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to determine which rule of a specific field is activated in codeigniter?

```
$rule = [
        'field' => 'field_name',
        'label' => 'Field Name',
        'rules' => 'required|custom_rule|valid_email'
    ];
```

How will I check if the rule 'required' is activated and not the other 2?

edit:
Aside from the error message since the error message can be modified.

Edit:
The code above is just an example, what my code need is that I have to delete a specific record in my database. That parameter is a required field for me to be able to delete something in the database. But I also need to check something in a different table and that's the purpose of the custome rule. All I need is to be able to determine which of the rule is activated.
e.g

```
if ($activated_rule['required']) {
     //do something
} else if ($activated_rule['custom_rule']) {
     //do a different thing
}
```

Comment: Explain The question. Unclear what you are asking

Comment: Is this about form validation?

Answer (score -1):

Rules are evaluated in the order they are defined. In your question the order would be required, custom_rule then valid_email.

Validation of any particular field stops at the first rule that returns FALSE. So in your example, if required passes but custom_rule fails then valid_email will not be executed.

If there are no errors for a particular field then all the rules did run and tested OK.